# Zod object receiving undefined values from react-hook-form and shadcn Select components

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

I used shadcn Select and react-hook-form. I'd like to use Zod to validate the values, however, when I click the submit button, the Zod object receives undefined values for all the FormFields. `onSubmitSearch` is the submit handle, and `onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmitSearch)}` doesn't work/run because the values are not valid according to Zod. So I changed the code from `onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmitSearch)}` into `onSubmit={onSubmitSearch}`, and now `onSubmitSearch` is running and I saw the error in `const parsed = formSchema.parse({ ...e });`. It receives undefined values. What could be causing the problem? I'd appreciate any help.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Select,
  SelectTrigger,
  SelectValue,
  SelectContent,
  SelectItem
} from "../../../libs/shadcn/components/ui/select";
import { Skeleton } from "../../../libs/shadcn/components/ui/skeleton";
import {
  Form,
  FormControl,
  FormField,
  FormItem,
  FormMessage
} from "../../../libs/shadcn/components/ui/form";
import * as z from "zod";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { Button } from "../../../libs/shadcn/components/ui/button";

const SearchSection = ({ query }) => {
  const { data: dropdownValuesData, isFetching, isSuccess } = query;

  const formSchema = z.object({
    property_type: z.string(),
    developer_id: z.string(),
    location: z.string()
  });

  const form = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      property_type: "",
      developer_id: "",
      location: ""
    }
  });

  const onSubmitSearch = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    formSchema.parse({ ...e }); // error here
  };

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        onSubmit={onSubmitSearch}
        className="mt-10 mb-8 flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-center md:space-x-3 w-fit max-w-fit mx-auto"
      >
        <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row space-y-3 md:space-y-0 md:space-x-3 justify-evenly w-fit">
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="property_type"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <Select
                  onValueChange={field.onChange}
                  defaultValue={field.value}
                >
                  <FormControl>
                    <SelectTrigger className="py-1 px-2 rounded-md min-w-24 w-56 md:w-40 text-xs font-medium h-7 self-center">
                      <SelectValue placeholder="Property" />
                    </SelectTrigger>
                  </FormControl>
                  <SelectContent className="w-56 h-fit max-h-60 text-xs">
                    {isFetching ? (
                      <div className="flex space-x-2 place-content-center">
                        <Skeleton className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-gray-500" />
                        <Skeleton className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-gray-500" />
                        <Skeleton className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-gray-500" />
                        <Skeleton className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-gray-500" />
                      </div>
                    ) : isSuccess && dropdownValuesData ? (
                      dropdownValuesData.data.property_types.map(item => (
                        <SelectItem value={item.id.toString()} key={item.id}>
                          {item.property_type_name}
                        </SelectItem>
                      ))
                    ) : (
                      <h2 className="mt-2 text-center">No data available.</h2>
                    )}
                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="Developer"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <Select
                  onValueChange={field.onChange}
                  defaultValue={field.value}
                >
                  <FormControl>
                    <SelectTrigger className="py-1 px-2 rounded-md min-w-24 w-56 md:w-40 text-xs font-medium h-7 self-center">
                      <SelectValue placeholder="Developer" />
                    </SelectTrigger>
                  </FormControl>
                  <SelectContent className="w-56 h-fit max-h-60 text-xs">
                    {isFetching ? (
                      <div className="flex space-x-2 place-content-center">
                        <Skeleton className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-gray-500" />
                        <Skeleton className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-gray-500" />
                        <Skeleton className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-gray-500" />
                        <Skeleton className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-gray-500" />
                      </div>
                    ) : isSuccess && dropdownValuesData ? (
                      dropdownValuesData.data.real_estate_developers.map(
                        item => (
                          <SelectItem value={item.id.toString()} key={item.id}>
                            {item.real_estate_developer_name}
                          </SelectItem>
                        )
                      )
                    ) : (
                      <h2 className="mt-2 text-center">No data available.</h2>
                    )}
                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
          <FormField
            control={form.control}
            name="Location"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <FormItem>
                <Select
                  onValueChange={field.onChange}
                  defaultValue={field.value}
                >
                  <FormControl>
                    <SelectTrigger className="py-1 px-2 rounded-md min-w-24 w-56 md:w-40 text-xs font-medium h-7 self-center">
                      <SelectValue placeholder="Location" />
                    </SelectTrigger>
                  </FormControl>
                  <SelectContent className="w-56 h-fit max-h-60 text-xs">
                    {isFetching ? (
                      <div className="flex space-x-2 place-content-center">
                        <Skeleton className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-gray-500" />
                        <Skeleton className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-gray-500" />
                        <Skeleton className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-gray-500" />
                        <Skeleton className="h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-gray-500" />
                      </div>
                    ) : isSuccess && dropdownValuesData ? (
                      dropdownValuesData.data.cities_with_projects.map(
                        (item, key) => {
                          if (item != null) {
                            return (
                              <SelectItem value={item} key={key}>
                                {item}
                              </SelectItem>
                            );
                          } else null;
                        }
                      )
                    ) : (
                      <h2 className="mt-2 text-center">No data available.</h2>
                    )}
                  </SelectContent>
                </Select>
                <FormMessage />
              </FormItem>
            )}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-center md:justify-start mt-3 md:mt-0 self-center w-fit">
          <Button
            type="submit"
            className="bg-[#009889] hover:bg-[#008577] active:bg-[#007065] text-white rounded-md py-1 px-4 h-7 w-fit font-medium text-xs"
          >
            Search
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default SearchSection;
```

The error is this:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error ZodError: [   {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "property_type"
    ],
    "message": "Required"   },   {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "developer_id"
    ],
    "message": "Required"   },   {
    "code": "invalid_type",
    "expected": "string",
    "received": "undefined",
    "path": [
      "location"
    ],
    "message": "Required"   } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. One or more of my FormField name does not match the schema.

```
const formSchema = z.object({
    property_type: z.string(),
    developer_id: z.string(),
    location: z.string()
  });
```